# Use <a> in iframe (1) to load page into iframe (2)

Tags: html, iframe

I am setting up an `iframe` styled page. I have `iframe`s for each piece of my page (header, menu, sidebar, content, etc).

My menu `iframe` had links in it;

```
<ul id="workMenuItems" style="display:none">
    <li><a target="contentframe" href="work/courier.php" id="hrefcourier">Courier</a></li>
    <li><a target="contentframe" href="work/scout.php" id="hrefscout">Scout</a></li>
    <li><a target="contentframe" href="work/hunt.php" id="hrefhunt">Bounty Hunt</a></li>
    <li><a onclick="back()" href="javascript:void(0)" id="back">Back</a></li>
</ul>
```

When I click on any of these (courier for example) it opens a new tab instead of loading that `.php` into the `contentframe`. I checked spelling and everything matches.

Also - I am using Chrome - not sure if that's a known issue off hand.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a shot in the dark, I added the `name` element to my iframe and it worked. `ID=""` apparently isn't enough on this one. Thanks to anyone who looked!

Comment: In addition - I switched from using iframes to `<div>` with `<? php include "xxxx.php'; ?>` and it works even better. `CSS` works great to style with on these as well.